The method login(Customer) from the type CustomerDAO refers to the missing type CustomerJava(67108984)
i dont know why if i run this code in eclipse it says ok but in vsc is says error?
btw i use heroku and postsql for my project. the back end i use java.
i already imported all the file need still it cannot run
    package com.heroku.java;

    import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
    import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;
    import com.heroku.java.data_access_object.CustomerDAO;
    import com.heroku.java.model.Customer;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    @WebServlet("/CustomerAccountController")
    public class CustomerAccountController extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public CustomerAccountController() {
            super();
        }

        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            System.out.println("CustomerAccountController: processRequest called");
        }

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws                 ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println("CustomerAccountController: doGet called");
            processRequest(request, response);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println("CustomerAccountController: doPost called");
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            String source = request.getParameter("source");

            switch (source) {
                case "register":
                    System.out.println("register");
                    handleRegister(request, response, session);
                    break;
                case "login":
                    System.out.println("login");
                    handleLogin(request, response, session);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void handleLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String custEmail = request.getParameter("email");
            String custPass = request.getParameter("password");

            List<String> errMsgs = new LinkedList<>();

            // Validate email and password
            if (custEmail == null || custEmail.trim().isEmpty()) {
                errMsgs.add("Please enter your email");
            }
            if (custPass == null || custPass.trim().isEmpty()) {
                errMsgs.add("Please enter your password");
            }

            // If there are no error messages, attempt login
            if (errMsgs.isEmpty()) {
                Customer c = new Customer(custEmail, custPass);
                CustomerDAO cd = new CustomerDAO();
                String result = "";
                c.setCustEmail(custEmail);
                c.setCustPass(custPass);

                // Call the login method in CustomerDAO to perform login logic
                String loginResult = cd.login(c);

                if ("SUCCESS".equals(loginResult)) {
                    // Login successful, set session attributes and forward to a success page
                    session.setAttribute("custemail", custEmail); // Assuming you want to store the email in the session
                    // Redirect to a success page, for example:
                    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                } else if ("INVALID_CREDENTIALS".equals(loginResult)) {
                    // Login failed, add an error message and forward back to the login page
                    errMsgs.add("Invalid email or password. Please try again.");
                    request.setAttribute("errMsgs", errMsgs);
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
                } else {
                    // Handle other cases (e.g., DB_ERROR)
                    errMsgs.add("An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later.");
                    request.setAttribute("errMsgs", errMsgs);
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
            } else {
                // Validation failed, forward back to login.jsp
                request.setAttribute("errMsgs", errMsgs);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        }

        private void handleRegister(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String custName = request.getParameter("name");
            String custPhoneNum = request.getParameter("phone");
            String custDateOfBirth = request.getParameter("dateOfBirth");
            String custAddress = request.getParameter("address");
            String custPass = request.getParameter("password");
            String custEmail = request.getParameter("email");

            List<String> errMsgs = new LinkedList<>();

            // Validate input fields
            if (custName == null || custName.trim().isEmpty()) {
                errMsgs.add("Please enter your name");
            }
            if (custPhoneNum == null || custPhoneNum.trim().isEmpty()) {
                errMsgs.add("Please enter your phone number");
            }
            if (custDateOfBirth == null || custDateOfBirth.trim().isEmpty()) {
                errMsgs.add("Please enter your date of birth");
            }
            if (custAddress == null || custAddress.trim().isEmpty()) {
                errMsgs.add("Please enter your address");
            }
            if (custPass == null || custPass.trim().isEmpty()) {
                errMsgs.add("Please enter your password");
            }
            if (custEmail == null || custEmail.trim().isEmpty()) {
                errMsgs.add("Please enter your email");
            }

            // If there are no error messages, attempt registration
            if (errMsgs.isEmpty()) {
                Customer c = new Customer(custName, custPhoneNum, custDateOfBirth, custAddress, custPass, custEmail);
                CustomerDAO cd = new CustomerDAO();
                String result = cd.registerUser(c);

                if ("SUCCESS".equals(result)) {
                    // Registration successful, set session attributes and forward to a success page
                    session.setAttribute("custemail", custEmail); // Assuming you want to store the email in the session
                    // Redirect to a success page, for example:
                    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                } else if ("INVALID_DATE_FORMAT".equals(result)) {
                    // Date format invalid, add an error message and forward back to the registration page
                    errMsgs.add("Invalid date format. Please enter a valid date (yyyy-MM-dd).");
                    request.setAttribute("errMsgs", errMsgs);
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("register.jsp").forward(request, response);
                } else {
                    // Handle other cases (e.g., DB_ERROR)
                    errMsgs.add("An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later.");
                    request.setAttribute("errMsgs", errMsgs);
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("register.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
            } else {
                // Validation failed, forward back to register.jsp
                request.setAttribute("errMsgs", errMsgs);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("register.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        }
    }



`your text`package com.heroku.java.data_access_object;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import com.heroku.java.model.Customer;;

public class CustomerDAO {

    public String registerUser(Customer customer) {
        String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO customer (custname, custphone, custdateofbirth, custaddress, custpassword, custemail) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        
        try (Connection conn = new ConnectDB().get_connection();
             PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
             
            ps.setString(1, customer.getCustName());
            ps.setString(2, customer.getCustPhoneNum());
            
            // Parsing and setting the date of birth
            try {
                String dobString = customer.getCustDateOfBirth();
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(dobString);
                java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(parsedDate.getTime());
                ps.setDate(3, sqlDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "INVALID_DATE_FORMAT";
            }
            
            ps.setString(4, customer.getCustAddress());
            ps.setString(5, customer.getCustPass());
            ps.setString(6, customer.getCustEmail());
            
            int result = ps.executeUpdate();
            if (result > 0) {
                try (ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        int custid = rs.getInt(1);
                        customer.setCustID(String.valueOf(custid)); // Store the generated ID
                        return "SUCCESS";
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "DB_ERROR";
        }
        return "FAIL";
    }

    public String login(Customer customer) {
        String email = customer.getCustEmail();
        String password = customer.getCustPass();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE custemail = ? AND custpassword = ?";
        
        try (Connection conn = new ConnectDB().get_connection();
             PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
             
            ps.setString(1, email);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    // Login successful
                    return "SUCCESS";
                } else {
                    // Login failed, invalid credentials
                    return "INVALID_CREDENTIALS";
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "DB_ERROR";
        }
    }
}


this is my model named Customer
package com.heroku.java.model;

public class Customer {
    private String custID;
    private String custName;
    private String custPhoneNum;
    private String custDateOfBirth;
    private String custAddress;
    private String custPass;
    private String custEmail;

    public Customer(String custEmail, String custPass) {
        this.custEmail = custEmail;
        this.custPass = custPass;
    }

    public Customer(String custName, String custPhoneNum, String custDateOfBirth, String custAddress, String custPass, String custEmail) {
        this.custName = custName;
        this.custPhoneNum = custPhoneNum;
        this.custDateOfBirth = custDateOfBirth;
        this.custAddress = custAddress;
        this.custPass = custPass;
        this.custEmail = custEmail;
    }

    // Getter and Setter methods
    public String getCustID() { return custID; }
    public void setCustID(String custID) { this.custID = custID; }
    public String getCustName() { return custName; }
    public void setCustName(String custName) { this.custName = custName; }
    public String getCustPhoneNum() { return custPhoneNum; }
    public void setCustPhoneNum(String custPhoneNum) { this.custPhoneNum = custPhoneNum; }
    public String getCustDateOfBirth() { return custDateOfBirth; }
    public void setCustDateOfBirth(String custDateOfBirth) { this.custDateOfBirth = custDateOfBirth; }
    public String getCustAddress() { return custAddress; }
    public void setCustAddress(String custAddress) { this.custAddress = custAddress; }
    public String getCustPass() { return custPass; }
    public void setCustPass(String custPass) { this.custPass = custPass; }
    public String getCustEmail() { return custEmail; }
    public void setCustEmail(String custEmail) { this.custEmail = custEmail; }
}


please help me, i already check with chat gpt and idk what to do

What's all this: your textpackage com.heroku.java.data_access_object;? btw you should avoid underscores anywhere other than in constants
There's no reason that package shouldn't be called com.heroku.java.dao

If the problem is running from Visual Studio Code the issue is unrelated to Heroku. Please don't use irrelevant tags.
